# Stretch lists to fit each others sizes

Tags: python, numpy, sequence

Say I have 3 mismatched sizes of lists, `[3, 7, 6], [12, 67, 89, 98], and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`
I want a function to do this:

```
>>> stretch([3, 7, 6], [12, 67, 89, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
[3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6], [12, 67, 67, 89, 89, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

So, what I want is for all the smaller lists to be stretched to the length of the largest list. If there is 2 largest equally sized lists leave them the same length. I tried using one function, but it only worked using ranges. I would like it to work with everything. Here it is for reference:

```python3
import numpy

def zipstretch(*args):
        range_tups = [(x[0], x[-1]) for x in args]
        shifts = [x[0] for x in range_tups]
        range_tups = [(x[0]-y, x[1]-y, n) for x, y in zip(range_tups, shifts)]
        ranges = []
        for x, s in zip(range_tups, shifts):
            h = s
            temp = list()
            for y in range(max(range_tups, key=lambda z: len(z))[0], max(range_tups, key=lambda z: len(z))[1]):
                temp.append(h)
                h+=x[1]/max(range_tups, key=lambda z: len(z))[1]
            ranges.append(numpy.array(temp))
        return ranges
```

Comment: you want the stretched array to have specific elements i.e. with some patterens or random numbers ???

Comment: You need to further define your requirements. Why are there three 3's in the first stretched list and not three 7's, for example?

Comment: @rahlf23 If the sizes aren't multiples of each other than I would like the beginning element stretch to make up for the remaining elements needed to make the sizes match. *By stretch I mean both ways, less or more

Comment: @stackuser So shouldn't there be 2 `12`'s instead of 2 `2`'s for the second list?

Comment: @Ashe stretch means both ways, more **or** less. It's not a hard fast rule so whatever you can come up with is fine, as long as the sizes match

Comment: Both ways doesn't make any sense here? You're saying every list is increased to match length of longest list so clearly there's only one way-- getting bigger in size

Comment: So what is the rule here? Why does the first one have an extra of `[0]`, while the second one has an extra of everything _except_ `[0]`? You can't turn "more or less" into code; you need something specific.

Comment: @stackuser if you write code, it's supposed to perform somewhat consistently, aka it can't really have both outputs. In general at least. Unless you desire random outputs

Comment: @Ashe what I mean is that every other element is left at the same... growth per say, but the first one is what is changed to make the lists match all the way, which means it is smaller or larger in size

Comment: @abarnet I didn't mean that kind of more or less. I meant it literally, like more quantity or less quantity.

Comment: Okay, since it appears that is not possible, any solution to make the lists match in size but keeping the same order of elements is fine. That aspect about stretching the first element is not important to me, someone just asked for clarification so I gave it. It's not a rule to what I am asking

Comment: Also, for solving a problem like this, you should consider whether you can break it down into something simpler. For example, if you had a `stretch_seq(seq, oldlen, newlen)`, building this `stretch(*lists)` would be almost trivial. So why not try to write `stretch_seq` first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
def stretch(*lists):
    length = max([len(l) for l in lists])
    return [[l[i * len(l) // length] for i in range(length)]
            for l in lists]
```

It computes the the target length as the maximum over all lists, and then stretches the list based on their index, similar to how you would implement naïve, one-dimensional image scaling.

Comment: I know this is not important to stack overflow but I was using this to color sufaces of triangles by creating lines between points and lines between the pixels in the lines and I found no problems, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Not super Pythonic, Florian's answer is much better, but I wanted to post the answer I came up with anyway.

```
def stretch(*lists):
    max_len = max([len(l) for l in lists])
    stretched = []
    for l in lists:
        init_factor = factor = (max_len - 1) / len(l)
        new_l = []
        i = 0
        j = 1
        while j <= max_len:
            new_l.append(l[i])
            if j > factor:
                i += 1
                factor += init_factor
            j += 1
        stretched.append(new_l)
    return stretched

stretch([3, 7, 6], [12, 67, 89, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
# => [[3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6], [12, 12, 67, 67, 89, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```